# How can I show a dollar sign before the amount value when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript

When the checkbox is not checked it will show `$0.00`.

When I check the checkbox, it will show `1.00`. I want it to show `$1.00`. How can I do that?

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzmLZ/)

This is the code:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="$0.00">
<input type="checkbox" value="aa_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="aa_2">
<input type="checkbox" value="aa_3">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
var clickHandlers = (function () {
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1"),
        totalcost = document.getElementById("totalcost"),
// if this is always the last input in the form, we could avoid hitting document again with
// totalcost  = form1[form1.length - 1];
        sum = 0;
    form1.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var thisInput = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (thisInput.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
            if (thisInput.checked) {

                var val = thisInput.value, // "bgh_9.99"
                split_array = val.split("_"), // ["bgh", "9.99"]
                pay_out_value = split_array[1]; // "9.99"
                sum += parseFloat(pay_out_value); // 9.99


            }  else {
                if (thisInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox') {

                    var val = thisInput.value, // "bgh_9.99"
                    split_array = val.split("_"), // ["bgh", "9.99"]
                    pay_out_value = split_array[1]; // "9.99"
                    sum -= parseFloat(pay_out_value); // 9.99


                }
            }
            totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "$0.00";
        }
    }
    return null;
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? sum.toFixed(2) : "$0.00";
```

to

```
totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? "$" + sum.toFixed(2) : "$0.00";
                               ^
```

This will add $ before your price !

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EzmLZ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Just append the $ to the value:

```
totalcost.value = (sum > 0) ? '$' + sum.toFixed(2) : "$0.00";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzmLZ/1/)